# Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[ ] fails to detect intersections

Tags: graphics, bugs, computational-geometry, undocumented, intersection

`` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[ ] `` is an undocumented function for, well, detecting intersections very efficiently. Take a look:

```
i = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcWcz.png";
perim = ImageValuePositions[Thinning@EdgeDetect@i, 1];
fcp = FindCurvePath[perim];
perimPts = perim[[First@fcp]];
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]; (*not sure if needed*)
myLine = Line@{1.1 {750.5`, 955.5`}, {182.5`, 671.5`}};
pts = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{myLine, Polygon@perimPts}];
Graphics[{Line@perimPts, Red, myLine, Green, PointSize[Large], 
          Point@pts}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it doesn't work consistently (here I change `myLine`):

```
myLine = {Line@{{750.5`, 955.5`}, {182.5`, 671.5`}}, 
          Line@{{622.5`, 1031.5`}, {222.5`, 831.5`}}};
pts = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{#, Polygon@perimPts}] & /@ myLine;
Graphics[{Line@perimPts, Red, Sequence @@ myLine, Green, 
          PointSize[Large], Point /@ pts}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there something that can be done about this behavior?

Comment: `(1. + 2 $MachineEpsilon)` already works and `(1.-$MachineEpsilon)` too (instead of 1.1). How special is this special case?

Comment: @Rojo Not special at all. It fails a lot

Comment: I've come across this problem before, sadly I know of no way to fix it :-(

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks for letting me know. I was almost thinking I'm the only one!

Comment: @Rojo see edit, please

Comment: Using `InfiniteLine[]` instead of `Line[]` might work( tested with the code  of Ali Hashmi-answer) !

Answer (score 4):

(Not an answer, just an illustrated comment)

Let us look closer where the points missing on the plot shown by the OP are located:

```
Graphics[{Blue, Line@perimPts, PointSize[Large], Point@perimPts, Red, myLine}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> #, 
   GridLines -> Automatic] & /@ 
 {{{323, 326}, {881, 884}}, {{624, 626}, {892, 894}}, {{548, 550}, {994, 996}}}
```

> [image: output]

Two missing intersection points are located exactly at the nodes of the polyline, while the third point isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem might be in the way we preprocess the image. Here is a fix:

```
(* finding the boundary *)
i = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcWcz.png";
img = MorphologicalPerimeter@Binarize@FillingTransform@ColorNegate@i;
boundaryx = PixelValuePositions[img, 1];
path = FindShortestTour[boundaryx][[2]];
boundaryx = boundaryx[[path]];



myLine = Line@{1.1 {750.5`, 955.5`}, {182.5`, 671.5`}};
gr = Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], Polygon@boundaryx, Red, myLine}];
pts = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], Polygon@boundaryx, myLine}]];
Show[gr, Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Darker@Green, Point@pts}]]
```

[image]

```
myLine = {Line@{{750.5`, 955.5`}, {182.5`, 671.5`}}, 
Line@{{622.5`, 1031.5`}, {222.5`, 831.5`}}};
gr = Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue], Polygon@boundaryx, myLine}];
pts = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{#, Polygon@boundaryx}] & /@ myLine;
Show[gr, Graphics[{Red,Sequence @@ myLine,Darker@Green,
PointSize[Large], Point /@ pts}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

Comment: It is interesting that with the `perimPts` of OP ``Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections`` works correctly if we apply `Ceiling` of `Floor` to `perimPts`, but applying `Round` reveals another bug.