# How to get the coordinates of the intersection of two lines from a ListLinePlot?

Tags: graphics, equation-solving, interpolation

**Suppose I have two curves intersect at some point, how can I read the coordinates from the graph, not read by eye, but find it with more precision by computer.**

For example, here are two lists created by simple functions just for illustration. However, the true list is not created by simple functions. So, using `FindRoot` is not welcomed. Also, do not assume the points is very dense, so that you can just find the coordinates from the two list with the shortest length. For the sparse points, the coordinates got in that way will have a large error.

For your convenience, you can start with the following code:

```
lst1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5, 0.5}];
lst2 = Table[{x, x + 3}, {x, 0, 5, 0.5}];
GraphicsRow[{ListLinePlot[{lst1, lst2}], ListPlot[{lst1, lst2}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: ...actually, you can still use `FindRoot[]`. Build the piecewise linear interpolating function for both sets (use `Interpolation[]`), eyeball the possible intersection point, and use `FindRoot[]` to find the intersection of the two `InterpolatingFunction[]`s generated, using your eyeballed value as the seed.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your comment, I answered it myself.

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [(7779387)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7779387/618728)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The internal function `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` has [limitations that are not well understood](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/graphicsmeshfindintersections-fails-to-detect-intersections), but it can be applied directly to plots.  For normal plots, it has always worked for me.  It will find all the intersections, too, if there are more than one.

```
lst1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5, 0.5}];
lst2 = Table[{x, x + 3}, {x, 0, 5, 0.5}];
plot = ListLinePlot[{lst1, lst2}]

Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections@plot
(*  {{2.28571, 5.28571}}  *)
```

To compare with the OP's answer using `Interpolation`, this method is equivalent to using `InterpolationOrder -> 1`.

```
f = Interpolation[lst1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
g = Interpolation[lst2, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
{x, f[x]} /. FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, 2.1}]
(*  {2.28571, 5.28571}  *)
```

The default interpolation order, which is cubic, gives a slightly different answer:

```
f = Interpolation[lst1];
g = Interpolation[lst2];
{x, f[x]} /. FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, 2.1}]
(*  {2.30278, 5.30278}  *)
```

This agrees exactly with the roots of the functions used to construct the lists because those functions, `x^2` and `x + 3`, have degrees that do not exceed the interpolation order (and there are a sufficient number of data points).

Comment: Note that whether the apparent improvement in accuracy from using the higher interpolation order is significant in a given problem should probably be considered in conjunction with the data, its source, and the model underlying the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way is to use the interpolation of one set of points as an appropriate mesh function in the plot of the other.

Here

```
mf = Interpolation[lst2];
```

and

```
plt = ListLinePlot[lst1, MeshFunctions -> (#2 - mf[#1] &), Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

You can then extract the point with

```
plt// Cases[Normal@#, Point[a_] :> a, Infinity] &
(*{{2.28571, 5.28571}}*)
```

Comment: +1.  Funny I just used this (some days ago) in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function/97898#97898).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just +1'ed yours there, it's indeed the same idea! Silvia's answer on that question has got me thinking of mesh functions as useful things.

Answer (score 6):

Following the comment by @J.M., here is a solution:

```
lst1 = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5, 0.5}];
lst2 = Table[{x, x + 3}, {x, 0, 5, 0.5}];
GraphicsRow[{ListLinePlot[{lst1, lst2}], ListPlot[{lst1, lst2}]}]
f = Interpolation[lst1];
g = Interpolation[lst2];
cords = {x = x /. FindRoot[f[x] == g[x], {x, 2.1}], f[x]}
cordsExact = {x /. FindRoot[x^2 == x + 3, {x, 2.1}], x^2}
```

cheers!