# How I show the case numbers on a plot?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have the following code:

```
data = Transpose @ {
          {2, 4, 7, 2, 19, 2, 4, 6, 2, 8, 5},
          {222, 250, 213, 150, 120, 154, 245, 235, 200, 100, 450}
        }; 
glm = GeneralizedLinearModelFit[data, x, x, ExponentialFamily -> "Gamma"];
h = glm["HatDiagonal"];
hP = FindPeaks[h, 0, 0, 0.5]
ListLinePlot[
  {h, hP}, 
  Joined -> {True, False}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"Index", "h"}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14], TicksStyle -> Black, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Black, PointSize[0.03]}}, 
  Epilog -> Line[{{0, 0.5}, {25, 0.5}}]
]
```

This generates the following plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is my question: **How do we show the case number which crosses the `Epilog` line instead of `Point`?**
My Question is not to show the two intersection points but the point which crosses the Epilog line. here this point is 5th. How I show the case 5 as indicated on a plot but not showing black bold point?.

Comment: We can't run your code because we don't have your data, so we can't help you. Please provide data, make sure that the code runs as posted. Also, removing all the superfluous formatting from your `ListLinePlot` will make your code more readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Labeling points of intersection between plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32081/labeling-points-of-intersection-between-plots)

Answer (score 4):

You should look at the following existing answers that pose essentially the same problem you have:

- [Marking points of intersection between two curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10472/27951)
- [Finding the intersection of a curve with an interpolation function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42304/27951)
- [Labeling points of intersection between plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32081/27951)
- [How to read the intersect coordinate of two lines from the ListLinePlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98329/27951)

You can modify your code as follows:

```
ListLinePlot[

  {h, hP}, Joined -> {True, False},

  Mesh -> {{0.5}},
  MeshFunctions -> {(#2&)},
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]],

  Epilog -> Line[{{0, 0.5}, {25, 0.5}}],

  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"Index", "h"}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14], TicksStyle -> Black, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Black, PointSize[0.03]}}

]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here's one way to label the point that goes above the threshold:

```
ListLinePlot[
  h,

  Epilog -> {
    Line[{{0, 0.5}, {25, 0.5}}],
    Text[Style[hP[[1, 1]], 14, Red], First@hP + {0.05, 0.05}]
    },

  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"Index", "h"}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14], TicksStyle -> Black
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: dear how i show the case number 5 instead of black bold point? only determining one point or points which croses Epilog line (Cut-point) but not two intersection points. In this case we want to show the 5th case on a plot

Comment: (+1) you could use `{#2&}` for the `MeshFunctions` setting.

Comment: @kglr D'oh! Of course! Thank you for pointing it out, I amended the answer.