# How I show multiple cases on a plot?

Tags: plotting

This code is for detecting one point. How can I make the code work for multiple point detecting. Consider the data

```
h = {0.1183, 0.102438, 0.0548574, 0.136082, 0.0894574, 0.0756707,
0.123306, 0.103845, 0.121702, 0.0851771, 0.060151, 0.0849629,
0.292271, 0.106089, 0.054503, 0.0572408, 0.0553025, 0.0550774, 
0.0566017, 0.571394, 0.113782, 0.631435, 0.25504, 0.595315}

hP = FindPeaks[h, 0, 0, 0.33]

ListLinePlot[h, 
  Epilog -> 
    {Line[{{0, 0.33}, {25, 0.33}}], 
     Text[
       Style[hP[[1, 1]], 14, Black, Bold], 
       First @ hP + {0.33, 0.33}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 1}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Index", "h"}, 
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14], 
   TicksStyle -> Black]
```

How can I modify this code to show multiple cases?

Comment: Multiple cases *of what*?

Comment: the cases which crosses 0.33, here these cases are indicated in  hP = FindPeaks[h, 0, 0, 0.33] command.

Comment: Is this different than you [previous post that was recently closed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108991/how-i-show-the-case-numbers-on-a-plot)? If so, you should attempt to edit *that* question so that it is more clear what you are asking. It might then be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {0.1183, 0.102438, 0.0548574, 0.136082, 0.0894574, 0.0756707, 
   0.123306, 0.103845, 0.121702, 0.0851771, 0.060151, 0.0849629, 
   0.292271, 0.106089, 0.054503, 0.0572408, 0.0553025, 0.0550774, 
   0.0566017, 0.571394, 0.113782, 0.631435, 0.25504, 0.595315};

hP = FindPeaks[h, 0, 0, 0.33]

{{20, 0.571394}, {22, 0.631435}, {24, 0.595315}}
```

Assuming that you want each peak labeled with its index

```
ListLinePlot[h,
 Epilog -> {
   Line[{{0, 0.33}, {25, 0.33}}],
   (Text[Style[#[[1]], 14, Bold], #, {0, -1}] & /@ hP)},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 1}},
 AxesLabel -> {"Index", "h"},
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14],
 TicksStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Thanks. But another problem that I face. consider h={0.641893, 0.356247, 0.121902, 0.134858, 0.0481972, 0.0687847,
0.367323, 0.367323, 0.124468, 0.125757, 0.122419, 0.147883, 0.109586, 
0.185172, 0.0775378, 0.066863, 0.234845, 0.126228, 0.136709, 
0.0890434, 0.346961} 
hP= FindPeaks[h,0,0,0.29]
why this command gives 15/2 result at 2end peak?

Comment: @Amin - because entries `7` and `8` are identical. The [FindPeaks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html) algorithm assumes that the "peak" is midway between identical entries because the default interpolation order is `1`.

Comment: @Amin - If you want to see both "peaks" use `hP = hP /. {n_Rational, val_} :> Sequence[{(2 n - 1)/2, val}, {(2 n + 1)/2, val}]`. Note that this will not suffice if there is a sequence of more than two identical values.

Comment: Dear Bob Hanlon Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
maxY = Max @@ hP[[All, 2]];
ListLinePlot[h, 
  Epilog -> 
    {Line[{{0, 0.33}, {25, 0.33}}], 
     Text[Style[#[[1]], 14, Black, Bold], {#[[1]], maxY + .075}] & /@ hP}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {0, 1}},
  AxesLabel -> {"Index", "h"},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14],
  TicksStyle -> Black]
```

[image: plot]