# How to get the x-coordinate of a region by it's y-value

Tags: bugs, regions

I get region like this:

```
region = ConvexHullMesh[data = RandomReal[{0, 100}, {100, 2}]] // 
  RegionBoundary
```

[image]

Then I get a equally spaced y-value from minimum to maximum.

```
yrange = data[[All, -2]] // MinMax;
y = Subdivide[Sequence @@ yrange, 10]
```

> {0.235321, 10.1105, 19.9857, 29.861, 39.7362, 49.6114, 59.4866, \
>   69.3618, 79.237, 89.1122, 98.9875}

When I wanna get the x-value by these y-value in this region,the warning in my procedure.But I think have no syntax errors in  [RegionMember](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember.html)'s usage.

```
Solve[#, x] & /@ (RegionMember[region, {x, #}] & /@ y)
```

[image]

Or another way is failure to make it.

```
RegionIntersection[region, #] & /@ (ImplicitRegion[#, {x, yy}] & /@ 
   Thread[yy == y])
```

[image]

So are there better way to get the x-coordinate which is corresponding the region?Please the answer explain these two reason where failure to it and give a method to get the right x-coordinates.I will appreciate you very much.

***Update:***
I'm appreciate @JasonB.But its answer doesn't metion the reason,especially the kind of second method.I think it is a bug of `RegionIntersection`.Please everyone have a affirm and I'll attach a `bug` label to help improve `Mathematica`.

Comment: In English the error message is "... is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities."

Comment: @JasonB Thinks for your comments,and I will change it for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definitely seems like a bug in `RegionIntersection`, and you can confirm it using this simple example.

Take two `Region` objects, one an `ImplicitRegion` defined along a horizontal line, the other a unit square.  This error shows up regardless of whether `RegionBoundary` is used to define the region, so we'll leave it out.

```
region1 = Rectangle[];
line1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 1/2, {x, y}];
{RegionPlot[{region1, line1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1.1}, {-.1, 1.1}}],
 DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[line1, region1]}
```

[image]

No problem there, as `RegionIntersection` had no trouble, and we were able to discretize the resulting intersection.  If however, we defined the region using an explicit set of points (in a way that it should be the exact same region), then we can't find the intersection

```
region1b = ConvexHullMesh[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}];
line1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 1/2, {x, y}];
{RegionPlot[{region1b, line1}, PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1.1}, {-.1, 1.1}}],
 DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[line1, region1b]}
```

[image]

The problem seems to be that `RegionIntersection` cannot find the intersection between a 2D `MeshRegion` and a 1D region.  In the example above, `region1` is not a `MeshRegion` while `region1b` is.  If we try it again, this time making the exact same region with `ImplicitRegion`, we have no problem,

```
region1c = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}];
line1 = ImplicitRegion[y == 1/2, {x, y}];
{RegionPlot[{region1c, line1}, PlotRange -> {{-.1, 1.1}, {-.1, 1.1}}],
  DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[line1, region1c]}
```

[image]

The documentation for [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) doesn't mention this problem, it only says that the two regions should have the same `RegionEmbeddingDimension`, which they do. That seems pretty conclusive to be a bug.  Regions are fairly new, and there are lots of kinks left to work out.

The same problem applies to `Solve`,

```
Solve[RegionMember[RegionBoundary[#], {x, 1/2}], x] & /@ {region1, 
  region1b, region1c}
```

[image]

So we can narrow down that the problem is finding intersections between  2D `MeshRegion` and `BoundaryMeshRegion` objects and 1D regions.

But your question "How to get the x-coordinate of a region by it's y-value" has a workable solution.  You can't use `Solve`, `RegionNearest` will give you the nearest point and not keep the same `y` value, `NMinimize` will only give one `x` value, so what we are left with is `FindRoot`. Here is the best way I can find to get both of the `x` values for a given `y` value in your example.

```
region = ConvexHullMesh[
    data = Rationalize@RandomReal[{0, 100}, {100, 2}]] // 
   RegionBoundary;
(*You originally had -2 here, seems like a typo*)

yrange = data[[All, 2]] // MinMax;
xrange = data[[All, 1]] // MinMax;

yvalues = Subdivide[Sequence @@ yrange, 10];
xvalues = x /. {
    (Quiet@
        FindRoot[RegionDistance[region, {x, #}], {x, xrange[[1]]}] & /@
       yvalues), (Quiet@
        FindRoot[RegionDistance[region, {x, #}], {x, xrange[[2]]}] & /@
       yvalues)};
Show[
 RegionPlot[region],
 ListPlot[{
   Transpose[{xvalues[[1]], yvalues}],
   Transpose[{xvalues[[2]], yvalues}]}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

**Edit**

@yode, as to your last comment, `RegionDistance` returns a number, which is why we can use it with `NMinimize`, while `RegionMember` returns a truth value, which is why we can often use it with `Solve`, `Reduce`, or `NSolve`.  *Mathematica* is able to simplify the truth statement when the `Region` is defined via a geometric object, or a call to `ImplicitRegion`, but not when it is numerically defined as a `MeshRegion`.

I still think that you **should** be able to use `NSolve` in this case, but as we see above, many of the functions that work with regions fail when using `MeshRegion` objects.

Comment: But when you run `Solve[RegionMember[Circle[], {x, 0.1}], x]`,you will get the answer `{{x -> -0.994987}, {x -> 0.994987}}`

Comment: @yode, evaluate the code `RegionMember[Circle[], {x, 0.1}]` and it returns `x \[Element] Reals && 0.01 + x^2 == 1`.  However, `RegionMember[region, {x, .1}]` does not return an equation.

Comment: Do you have seem my second way?It have a slightly strange too.

Comment: I don't really know why the two methods you use don't work.  But I'm curious whether the method I propose works for your problem.

Comment: Oh.Thanks for your help sincerely. ^_^

Comment: Thanks for your second edited answer.It help me a lot.BTW the `RegionDistance[region, {x, yvalues[[1]]}]` will not return an equation.The `FindRoot` will get the x-value.But the `RegionMember[region, {x, yvalues[[1]]}]` will fail to it by the same `FindRoot`.Some mysterious problem haunt me still.

Comment: You make well reasoned points in the **Edit**.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, this is a way to do it in V9:

```
<< ComputationalGeometry`
SeedRandom[42];
l = RandomReal[{0, 50}, {100, 2}];
{xr, yr} = Through[{Min, Max}[#]] & /@ Transpose@l;
mylines = Line/@(Thread[{xr + {-1,1}, #}]&/@  Range[Sequence @@ yr, -Subtract @@ yr/10]);
gc = GraphicsComplex[l, {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@ConvexHull[l]}];
gmf = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections;
pts = Flatten[gmf[{#, gc}] & /@ mylines, 1];
pts = Join[pts, gmf[{Line @@ (# - {0, 10000 $MachineEpsilon} & /@ 
                                                         List @@ mylines[[-1]]), gc}]];
Graphics[{mylines, gc, Black, Point@l, PointSize@Large, Red, Point@pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your method Impressive me deeply with ``Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections`` .But I think `pts = Join[pts***` can be omited?

Comment: @yode There is a bug in `FindIntersections` on some  MMa versions. See for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41496/193. The `Join` part tries to address it

Comment: @yode On behalf of the academic community I remind you that academic titles don't suffer the "my" add-on. [You may want to apply Mma on military projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Captain!_My_Captain!), though :)