# Fast function to do multiple rectangle region checks

Tags: performance-tuning, regions, packed-arrays

Suppose I have a set of "rectangles" and a set of "points":

```
SeedRandom[5]
rects = RandomReal[10, {5, 2, 2}]
pts = RandomReal[10, {5, 2}]
```

> {{{0.00790584, 0.650192}, {9.89555, 9.68768}}, {{2.00866, 8.19521}, {0.897634,
>       9.70701}}, {{2.2991, 6.12503}, {0.96816, 5.48855}}, {{1.32548, 
>      2.32332}, {7.76135, 5.50949}}, {{0.586896, 9.60602}, {0.982487, 0.343521}}}
>
> {{8.06562, 4.39186}, {1.42284, 0.27687}, {0.794711, 8.59505}, {2.42136, 
>     8.42835}, {5.54556, 7.21645}}

I want to find out which points are members of their associated rectangles. One slow possibility is to use [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember):

```
MapThread[RegionMember[Rectangle@@#1, #2]&, {rects, pts}]
```

> {True, RegionMember[
>     Rectangle[{2.00866, 8.19521}, {0.897634, 9.70701}], {1.42284, 0.27687}], 
>    RegionMember[
>     Rectangle[{2.2991, 6.12503}, {0.96816, 5.48855}], {0.794711, 
>      8.59505}], False, 
>    RegionMember[
>     Rectangle[{0.586896, 9.60602}, {0.982487, 0.343521}], {5.54556, 7.21645}]}

This approach doesn't work because [`RegionMember`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMember) needs the first [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle) coordinate to be strictly smaller than the second [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle) coordinate. It also unpacks the `rects` variable. I would like a function `inRange` that returns 1 if the point is in the rectangle, and 0 otherwise, and I want to avoid unpacking. For the above example:

```
inRange[rects, pts]
```

should return:

```
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

A compiled solution is acceptable, but I would prefer a version that works  for both packed arrays and mixed data types.

An alternate version using vectors only is fine, e.g.:

```
inRange[x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y]
```

A 1D version would also be interesting, with intervals instead of rectangles. The simplest approach in that case would be to use IntervalMemberQ, but that would cause unpacking.

Comment: Also I think we can reduce this to a 1D problem since your regions are rectangles. Take the 1D intervals for x coordinates and the 1D intervals for the y coordinates. The final answer would be the indices that satisfy both 1D cases.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
inRect[{{xmin_, ymin_}, {xmax_, ymax_}}, {px_, py_}] := 
  Boole[xmin <= px <= xmax && ymin <= py <= ymax];
inRange[rects_, points_] := inRect @@@ Transpose[{rects, points}];

inRange[rects, pts]
(* {1, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

A compiled solution has the advantage, that it can determine the correct level of listable:

```
inRangeC = Compile[{{r, _Real, 2}, {p, _Real, 1}},
  Boole[r[[1, 1]] <= p[[1]] <= r[[2, 1]] && 
    r[[1, 2]] <= p[[2]] <= r[[2, 2]]],
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
  ]

inRangeC[rects, pts]
```

## Edit

It was not clear from the original post that the assumption that `xmin <= xmax` and `ymin<=ymax` does not hold. This can be incorporated easily in the same style as Carl does with `UnitStep`.

```
inRangeC = Compile[{{r, _Real, 2}, {p, _Real, 1}},
  If[
    (-p[[1]] + r[[1, 1]]) (p[[1]] - r[[2, 1]]) < 0 || 
    (-p[[2]] + r[[1, 2]]) (p[[2]] - r[[2, 2]]) < 0,
    0,
    1
   ],
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
]
```

While I don't agree with the way Carl measures the running time, I agree that a pure high-level implementation that is so short is preferable. But if you have data in a certain format, which seems to be a list of rectangles and a list of points, and your function needs to change the layout to operate on it, you need to include this change of layout in the running time (same is true for the compilation time, but this needs to be done only once).

Comment: Your solution assumes that `xmin` is less than `xmax`, but my example for `rects` doesn't satisfy this constraint. You would need to include `xmin>=px>=xmax` as well to allow for arbitrarily specified rectangles.

Comment: Yes, this is true. I assumed you were using the standard definition of `Rectangle` in your real application and that I can count on this assumption. Although `Rectangle` works with wrongly defined regions, the Details section in its documentation (third line) clearly states the condition I have used. It is a simple fix though

Comment: I have an application in mind where the rectangles are constructed in such a way that the first point is not guaranteed to be the lower left corner. I would prefer to avoid pre-processing the rectangles to get them in the right form.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest method I can think of is to use [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep) in the vector approach:

```
inRange[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_, x_, y_] := UnitStep[(x1-x)(x-x2)] UnitStep[(y1-y)(y-y2)]
```

A comparison with @halirutan's [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile) approach (modified to allow rectangle specifications where the first point is not necessarily the lower left coordinate):

```
rects = RandomReal[10, {10^6, 2, 2}];
pts = RandomReal[10, {10^6, 2}];

x1 = rects[[All, 1, 1]];
y1 = rects[[All, 1, 2]];
x2 = rects[[All, 2, 1]];
y2 = rects[[All, 2, 2]];

x = pts[[All, 1]];
y = pts[[All, 2]];

r1 = inRange[x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = inRangeC[rects, pts]; //RepeatedTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.0192, Null}
>
> {0.061, Null}
>
> True

Comment: (+1) Using `Subtract` instead of `Plus` gives about a 20% speedup on my machine.