# Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections get extra intersections

Tags: intersection

Why am I getting some extra intersection points?[image]

```
 Manipulate[b = 2 r + 1;
 Show[p1 = 
   ContourPlot[{x^2 + (y - r)^2 == r^2, x/12 + y/b == 1}, {x, -20, 
     20}, {y, -20, 20}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, PerformanceGoal -> "Goal"],
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[p1]}]], {{r, 4, 
   "Radius"}, -10, 10, 0.01}]
```

Why is this not plotting the right

**Obviously, this should not have intersection in the pic above.**

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/graphicsmeshfindintersections-fails-to-detect-intersections  --  IIRC: The operation of `FindIntersections` changes from time to time, and several users would not base important code on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You can use `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[p1, Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False] `` to eliminate extra points; however, it will also miss the tangent point. It is easy to just solve for the intersections.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[
  {sol, b, eqns},
  b = 2 r + 1;
  eqns = {x^2 + (y - r)^2 == r^2, x/12 + y/b == 1};
  sol = Solve[eqns, {x, y}, Reals] // Quiet;
  ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqns,
   {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20},
   Axes -> True,
   Frame -> False,
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   PerformanceGoal -> "Goal",
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red,
     If[Length@sol > 0, Point[{x, y} /. sol], Nothing]}]],
 {{r, 4, "Radius"}, -10, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: corrected plot with the tangent as the single intersection]

Comment: Coordinate {{ConditionalExpression[$CellContext`b^(-1) (12 $CellContext`b - 12 (4 (144 + $CellContext`b^2)^(-1) (36 $CellContext`b + $CellContext`b^2) - 8 2^Rational[1, 2] (-(144 + $CellContext`b^2)^(-2) ((-9) $CellContext`b^3 + $CellContext`b^4))^Rational[1, 2])), should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Comment: The line is not moving with the slider

Comment: @kile - restructured the `Module`. Try it now.