# Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections not working in Mathematica 13.3

Tags: plotting, mesh, undocumented, intersection, version-13.3

I just updated my Mathematica for Windows to 13.3 and when I tried to use the "Graphics MeshFindIntersections" command it doesn't seem to work. Have they replaced it with some other command or is it a bug in the new update?

**Code used**

```
T[rh_, Q_, P_] := 1/(4 \[Pi] rh) (1 + 8 \[Pi] P rh^2 - Q^2/rh^2)
M[rh_, Q_, P_] := rh/2 + (4 \[Pi] P rh^3)/3 + Q^2/(2 rh)
V[rh_] := 4/3 \[Pi] rh^3
S[rh_] := \[Pi] rh^2
G[rh_, Q_, P_] = Simplify[M[rh, Q, P] - (T[rh, Q, P] S[rh])];
{rc, Pc} = 
  SolveValues[{D[T[rh, Q, P], {rh, 2}] == 0, 
     D[T[rh, Q, P], rh] == 0}, {rh, P}][[2]];
Vc = V[rc]; Tc = T[rc, Q, Pc]; Gc = G[rc, Q, Pc];
T = t Tc; P = p Pc; rh = z rc; G = g Gc;
t[z_, p_] = 
  SolveValues[{T == 1/(4 \[Pi] rh) (1 + 8 \[Pi] P rh^2 - Q^2/rh^2)}, 
    t][[1]];
g[z_, p_] = 
  SolveValues[{G == (3 Q^2)/(4 rh) + rh/4 - 2/3 P \[Pi] rh^3}, g][[1]];
pplt = ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{t[z, 0.5], g[z, 0.5]}, {z, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.6, 1.3}, {0.8, 1.3}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
ip = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections@pplt
```

Comment: Can you please load the code that failed?

Comment: Sure.  One minute, let me edit it!

Comment: `T` is a function name **and** a parameter name!

Comment: Ah my mistake! Even if I change the name, the problem still exists.

Comment: t and g diverge at zero. Therefore, you can not plot from zero. You may plot z e.g.:{z, 0.1, 10}

Comment: Ok I will try that. But will it rectify the intersection issue?

Comment: In the definitions `t[...],g[...]`the function arguments `z,p` don't appear on the righthand side! Again `t,g` are used as parameter names too, what's probably wrong

Comment: Its unreliability goes back a ways: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41496/graphicsmeshfindintersections-fails-to-detect-intersections

Comment: Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216084/graphicsmeshfindintersections-get-extra-intersections?rq=1#comment595957_216084

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$Version
```

> `"13.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"`

```
pt = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pplt // DiscretizeGraphics, 
  Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False]
Show[pplt, Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point@pt}]]
```

> `{{0.757021, 1.07072}}`

[image]

- It must be a bug. Here we test another example.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pp = ParametricPlot[{Sin[10 t], Sin[9 t]}, {t, 0, 2 π}];
intersections1 = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp];
intersections2 = 
  Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[pp // DiscretizeGraphics, 
   Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False];
{Show[pp, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@intersections1}], 
 Show[pp, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@intersections2}]}
```

[image]

Comment: Are the new constraints required for the new 13.3 version of Mathematica or are they just for this particular problem?

Comment: @codebpr Seems be a bug. Here just a working around.

Comment: @cvgmt And the code really runs on v13.3 without recursion error due to naming errors (function `T[...]`and parameter `T`) and others?? I tried v12.2 and got several errors.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Without any errors message in 13.3.1

Comment: @cvgmt Astonishing, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with `Annotation` is in [Finding intersection of two curves using mesh functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295922/finding-intersection-of-two-curves-using-mesh-functions/295923?noredirect=1#comment732525_295923):

```
Block[{Annotation = # &}, ip = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections@pplt]

(* {{0.757021, 1.07072}} *)
```