# Why can't NSolve find values that FindInstance can?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, numerics, numerical-value

I am trying to solve for `\[Epsilon]`, given three input paramters `n`, `x` and `eps`. Only `FindInstance` provides a solution for me whereas `NSolve` and `NSolveValues` fail.

Why does this happen?

```
$PreRead = (# /. 
     s_String /; 
       StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && 
        Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :> s <> "`50." &);

kldFunc[x_, y_] := x Log[x/y] + (1 - x) Log[(1 - x)/(1 - y)];

n = 10.^13.; x = 6. 10.^9.; eps = 10.^-20.; 

Clear[\[Epsilon], \[Mu], p]; 
\[Mu] = x + n \[Epsilon];
p = \[Mu]/n; 
\[Epsilon] = \[Epsilon] /. 
    Flatten[FindInstance[
      Exp[-kldFunc[p - \[Epsilon], p] n] == eps && 
       1. > \[Epsilon] > 0., \[Epsilon], Reals] ]

Clear[\[Epsilon], \[Mu], p]; 
\[Mu] = x + n \[Epsilon];
p = \[Mu]/n; 
\[Epsilon] = 
   NSolveValues[
    Exp[-kldFunc[p - \[Epsilon], p] n] == eps && 
     1. > \[Epsilon] > 0., \[Epsilon], Reals] 

Clear[\[Epsilon], \[Mu], p]; 
\[Mu] = x + n \[Epsilon];
p = \[Mu]/n; 
\[Epsilon] = 
   NSolve[Exp[-kldFunc[p - \[Epsilon], p] n] == eps && 
     1. > \[Epsilon] > 0., \[Epsilon], Reals]
```

EDIT

I tried plotting the two function to find the intersection

```
$PreRead = (# /. 
     s_String /; 
       StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && 
        Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :> 
      s <> "`100." &);
kldFunc[x_, y_] := x Log[x/y] + (1 - x) Log[(1 - x)/(1 - y)];
n = 10.^13.; x = 6.  10.^9.; eps = 10.^-20.; 



Clear[\[Epsilon], \[Mu], p]; 
\[Mu] = x + n \[Epsilon];
p = \[Mu]/n; 
Plot[{10^-20, Exp[-kldFunc[p - \[Epsilon], p] n]}, {\[Epsilon], 
  7 10^-8, 8  10^-8}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

[image]

I tried to extract the intersection point using

```
plot1 = Plot[
   Exp[-kldFunc[p - \[Epsilon], p] n], {\[Epsilon], 7 10^-8, 
    8  10^-8}, WorkingPrecision -> 50];
plot2 = Plot[10^-20, {\[Epsilon], 7 10^-8, 8  10^-8}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 50];


intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{plot2, plot1}]
```

but it does'nt give an output.(I'm running on 13.3. [See related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289187/graphicsmeshfindintersections-not-working-in-mathematica-13-3))

Comment: Per documentation for `NSolve`, Details and Options bullet item: "`NSolve` deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations.` It has only limited capabilities for handling transcendental equations.

Comment: So what can I use to solve such equations?.  `FindInstance` works most of the time but sometimes it runs for a couple of minutes without being able to find a solution.

Comment: Here is is your equation `E^(1.0...00*10^13 (-((1 +\[Epsilon] - 1.0...00*10^-13
(6.00...0*10^9 + 1.000...000*10^13\[Epsilon])) Log[( 1 + \[Epsilon] -  1.0000..0000*10^-13 
(6.0000...00*10^9 +  1.0000...000*10^13 \[Epsilon]))/( 1 - 1.0000..000*10^-13 
(6.00...0*10^9 + 1.000...0000*10^13 \[Epsilon]))]) - (-\[Epsilon] + 1.0000..0000*10^-13 (6.0000...0000*10^9 + 1.00...000*10^13 
\[Epsilon])) Log[( 1.000...000*10^13 (-\[Epsilon] +   1.0000...0000*10^-13 (6.00...000*10^9 +  1.00...00000*10^13 \[Epsilon])))/(   6.00000...0000*10^9 +  1.000..000000*10^13 \[Epsilon])])) == 1.0..0000000*10^-20`.

Comment: Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: `FindRoot` would be my go-to for this. `kldFunc[x_, y_] := x Log[x/y] + (1 - x) Log[(1 - x)/(1 - y)];
n = 10^13; x = 6 *10^9; eps = 10^-20;
\[Mu] = x + n \[Epsilon];
p = \[Mu]/n;

In[59]:= FindRoot[
 N[Exp[-kldFunc[p - \[Epsilon], p] n] - eps, 50] == 0, {\[Epsilon], 0,
   1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Out[59]= {\[Epsilon] -> 7.43192053584110156413007451123*10^-8}`

Comment: See the comment for the answer. I modified my input values to `n = 10^15; x = 6*10^9; eps = 10^-20; \[Mu] = x - n \[Epsilon]; p = \[Mu]/n`;, the code failed to converge to a solution.

Comment: Also see my edit. Is it possible to get reliable solutions from the plot intersection?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

kldFunc[x_, y_] := x Log[x/y] + (1 - x) Log[(1 - x)/(1 - y)];

n = 10^13; x = 6*10^9; eps = 10^-20;
μ = x + n ϵ;
p = μ/n;

expr = N[Exp[-kldFunc[p - ϵ, p] n] - eps, 100] // Simplify;
```

With `FindRoot` you need to provide a starting value and only a single result is returned irrespective of the number of roots.

```
(sol1 = FindRoot[expr == 0, {ϵ, 10^-8}, WorkingPrecision -> 80]) // N

(* {ϵ -> 7.43192*10^-8} *)

expr /. sol1

(* 0.*10^-94 *)

(sol2 = FindRoot[expr == 0, {ϵ, 10^-7}, WorkingPrecision -> 80]) // N

(* {ϵ -> 7.43192*10^-8} *)

expr /. sol2

(* 0.*10^-94 *)
```

With two starting values, `FindRoot` avoids the use of derivatives

```
(sol3 = FindRoot[expr == 0, {ϵ, 10^-9, 10^-6}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 80]) // N

(* {ϵ -> 7.43192*10^-8} *)

expr /. sol3

(* 0.*10^-94 *)
```

**EDIT:** For your revised values given in the comment

```
n = 10^15; x = 6*10^9; eps = 10^-20;
μ = x - n ϵ;
p = μ/n;
```

Increase the precision for `expr`

```
expr = N[Exp[-kldFunc[p - ϵ, p] n] - eps, 105] // Simplify;
```

The starting value must be close to the actual value

```
(sol4 = FindRoot[expr == 0, {ϵ, 7*10^-10}, WorkingPrecision -> 80]) //
  N

(* {ϵ -> 7.43321*10^-10} *)

expr /. sol4

(* 0.*10^-92 *)
```

Comment: This is nice and works a lot faster than my code.Thanks. However, as I modified my input values to `n = 10^15; x = 6*10^9; eps = 10^-20;
\[Mu] = x - n \[Epsilon];
p = \[Mu]/n;`, the code failed to converge to a solution

Answer (score 3):

`NSolve` work if we use infinite precision number `n,x,eps`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
kldFunc[x_, y_] := x Log[x/y] + (1 - x) Log[(1 - x)/(1 - y)];
n = 10^13; x = 6*10^9; eps = 10^-20;
μ = x + n ϵ;
p = μ/n;
NSolve[{Exp[-kldFunc[p - ϵ, p] n] == eps, 
  0 < ϵ < 10^-1}, ϵ]
```

> `{{ϵ -> 7.43192*10^-8}}`

- test another values.

```
NSolve[{Exp[-kldFunc[p - ϵ, p] n] == 10^-3, 
  0 < ϵ < 10^-1}, ϵ]
```

> `{{ϵ -> 2.8783*10^-8}}`