# Finding intersection of two curves using mesh functions

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, mesh, intersection

I have the following code which finds intersection of two curves using mesh functions:

```
y[x_] := x^2
z[x_] := 1
P1 = Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 2}];
P2 = Plot[z[x], {x, 0, 2}];
Test = Show[P1, P2]
Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Test // DiscretizeGraphics, 
 Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False]
```

This works well in all versions of Mathematica including Mathematica 13.3. But if I modify the code a little bit like this:

```
y[x_] := x^2
z[x_] := 1
P1 = Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 2}];
P2 = Graphics[{InfiniteLine[{{0, 1}, {2, 1}}]}];
Test = Show[P1, P2]
Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Test // DiscretizeGraphics, 
 Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False]
```

It works well on all Mathematica versions except Mathematica 13.3. Is this a bug in the latest version?

Comment: It's not a bug if WRI wants to change the behavior of an undocumented function. You really should report it and see what they say.  I don't know what ``Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False`` is supposed to do, but the function does not return all point, right?

Comment: Both code blocks evaluate in Mathematica v12.2!

Comment: suppress `PlotHighlighting` (new in version 13.3) using `P1 = Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotHighlighting -> None]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This maybe works like before:

```
Block[{Annotation = # &},
 Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[Test // DiscretizeGraphics, 
  Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False]
 ]

(* {{0.999811, 1.}} *)
```

Darned annotations.

My guess is that it's `DiscretizeGraphics` that behaves different, but prior behavior not given in OP.

Comment: Actually I use it on my Mathematica 13.3 because of this particular reason as mentioned in a previous question :
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289187/graphicsmeshfindintersections-not-working-in-mathematica-13-3

Comment: @codebpr Works there, too. See new answer.