# Finding intersection points graphically

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, intersection, table

> **"Code used in Mathematica version 13.3.1 on a Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 24, 2023) system"**

I used [@cvgmt's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/296146/78049) to find the intersection points from a parametric plot graphically:

```
$Assumptions = {r \[Element] Reals, r >= 0, rh \[Element] Reals, 
   rh > 0, Q \[Element] Reals, 
   Q >= 0, \[Lambda] \[Element] Reals, \[Lambda] > 1, 
   P \[Element] Reals, P >= 0, L \[Element] Reals, L > 0};
S[rh_] := \[Pi] rh^2;
\[Phi][rh_, Q_] := -((k Q)/rh^(\[Lambda] - 1))
\[CapitalLambda] := -8 \[Pi] P
M[rh_, Q_, P_] := 
 rh/2 - (k Q^2)/(2 rh^(\[Lambda] - 1)) - (rh^3 \[CapitalLambda])/6
T[rh_, Q_, P_] := 
 1/(4 \[Pi]) ((2 M[rh, Q, P])/rh^2 + (k Q^2 \[Lambda])/
    rh^(\[Lambda] + 1) - (2 \[CapitalLambda] rh)/3)
G[rh_, Q_, P_] := M[rh, Q, P] - (T[rh, Q, P] S[rh]) // Simplify
pplt[Q_] := 
 Block[{P = 3/(8 \[Pi]), k = -1, \[Lambda] = 4}, 
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{T[rh, Q, P], G[rh, Q, P]}, {rh, 0.001, 10},
    PlotRange -> {{0.265, 0.280}, {0.095, 0.110}}, 
   PlotHighlighting -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/2]]
Clear[intersections];
intersections[Q_] := 
 Region`Mesh`FindSegmentIntersections[
   Cases[Normal@pplt[Q], _Line, -1], "ReturnSegmentIndex" -> True, 
   "Ignore" -> {"EndPointsTouching"}][[1, 1]]
intersections /@ Range[0.0283, 0.0331, 0.0001]
```

which gives me the answer, but some intersection points are not being evaluated. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- This method depend on the plotting, it only work for the ideal cases.Here it only work for `MaxRecursion -> 2` and `Range[0.0283, 0.0331 - 0.0001*4, 0.0001]`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
 $Assumptions = {r ∈ Reals, r >= 0, 
  rh ∈ Reals, rh > 0, Q ∈ Reals, 
  Q >= 0, λ ∈ Reals, λ > 1, 
  P ∈ Reals, P >= 0, L ∈ Reals, L > 0};
S[rh_] := π  rh^2;
ϕ[rh_, Q_] := -((k  Q)/rh^(λ - 1))
Λ := -8  π  P
M[rh_, Q_, P_] := 
 rh/2 - (k  Q^2)/(2  rh^(λ - 1)) - (rh^3  Λ)/6
T[rh_, Q_, P_] := 
 1/(4  π)  ((2  M[rh, Q, P])/rh^2 + (k  Q^2  λ)/
     rh^(λ + 1) - (2  Λ  rh)/3)
G[rh_, Q_, P_] := M[rh, Q, P] - (T[rh, Q, P]  S[rh]) // Simplify
pplt[Q_] := 
 Block[{P = 3/(8  π), k = -1, λ = 4}, 
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate@{T[rh, Q, P], G[rh, Q, P]}, {rh, 0.001, 10},
    PlotRange -> {{0.265, 0.280}, {0.095, 0.110}}, 
   PlotHighlighting -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/2, MaxRecursion -> 2]]
Clear[intersections];
intersections[Q_] := 
 Region`Mesh`FindSegmentIntersections[
   Cases[Normal@pplt[Q], _Line, -1], "ReturnSegmentIndex" -> True, 
   "Ignore" -> {"EndPointsTouching"}][[1, 1]]
intersections /@ Range[0.0283, 0.0331 - 0.0001*4, 0.0001]
```

> `{{0.273623, 0.100382}, {0.273536, 0.10049}, {0.273449,  0.100598}, {0.273361, 0.100707}, {0.273274, 0.100816}, {0.273186,  0.100925}, {0.273098, 0.101035}, {0.273009, 0.101145}, {0.27292,  0.101256}, {0.272831, 0.101366}, {0.272742, 0.101478}, {0.272669,  0.101571}, {0.272601, 0.101659}, {0.272534, 0.101746}, {0.272467,  0.101833}, {0.272401, 0.101919}, {0.272336, 0.102004}, {0.27227,  0.102089}, {0.272205, 0.102175}, {0.27214, 0.102259}, {0.272076,  0.102344}, {0.272011, 0.102429}, {0.271946, 0.102514}, {0.271882,  0.102599}, {0.271817, 0.102683}, {0.271753, 0.102768}, {0.271688,  0.102853}, {0.271623, 0.102938}, {0.271552, 0.103026}, {0.271475,  0.103117}, {0.271398, 0.103208}, {0.271321, 0.103299}, {0.271243,  0.10339}, {0.271165, 0.103482}, {0.271086, 0.103574}, {0.271007,  0.103666}, {0.270928, 0.103759}, {0.270849, 0.103852}, {0.27077,  0.103943}, {0.2707, 0.104027}, {0.270635, 0.104107}, {0.270572,  0.104185}, {0.27051, 0.104262}, {0.270449, 0.104338}, {0.270388,  0.104414}}`

- For the original range  `Range[0.0283, 0.0331, 0.0001]`,it is recomment to use `Solve` or `FindInstance` to solve such problem. ( We `Rationalize` the equation to infinite precision to overcome  `s1 < s2`.)

```
f[Q_] := 
 Block[{P = 3/(8   π), k = -1, λ = 4}, 
  Evaluate@{T[rh, Q, P], G[rh, Q, P]}]; 
sol[Q_] := (f[Q] /. rh -> s1) /. 
  FindInstance[{Rationalize[(f[Q] /. rh -> s1) == (f[Q] /. rh -> s2), 
     0], 0 < s1 < s2 < 10}, {s1, s2}][[1]]
sol /@ Range[0.0283, 0.0331, 0.0001]
```

> `{{0.273525, 0.100504}, {0.273451, 0.100602}, {0.273376,  0.100699}, {0.273302, 0.100796}, {0.273228, 0.100892}, {0.273155,  0.100988}, {0.273081, 0.101084}, {0.273008, 0.101179}, {0.272934,  0.101273}, {0.272861, 0.101368}, {0.272788, 0.101461}, {0.272715,  0.101555}, {0.272642, 0.101648}, {0.27257, 0.10174}, {0.272497,  0.101833}, {0.272425, 0.101924}, {0.272353, 0.102016}, {0.272281,  0.102107}, {0.272209, 0.102197}, {0.272137, 0.102287}, {0.272066,  0.102377}, {0.271994, 0.102466}, {0.271923, 0.102555}, {0.271852,  0.102644}, {0.27178, 0.102732}, {0.271709, 0.10282}, {0.271639,  0.102907}, {0.271568, 0.102994}, {0.271497, 0.103081}, {0.271427,  0.103167}, {0.271357, 0.103253}, {0.271287, 0.103338}, {0.271217,  0.103423}, {0.271147, 0.103508}, {0.271077, 0.103592}, {0.271007,  0.103676}, {0.270938, 0.10376}, {0.270868, 0.103843}, {0.270799,  0.103926}, {0.27073, 0.104009}, {0.270661, 0.104091}, {0.270592,  0.104173}, {0.270523, 0.104254}, {0.270455, 0.104335}, {0.270386,  0.104416}, {0.270318, 0.104496}, {0.270249, 0.104576}, {0.270181,  0.104656}, {0.270113, 0.104735}}`

Comment: Which procedure gives more accurate values, the first one or the `FindInstance` one?

Comment: @codebpr  `Solve` or `FindInstance` is more accurate than the graphics method although   it is slower. ( We can replace `FindInstance` to `Solve` in the code, the result are the same.）